# Class Type Expected error on TableAdapter constructor

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server, oxygene

I am using Delphi Prism to connect to an Advantage Database Server. I created a connection using the server explorer to the database. I added a dataset object to my project and added a table to the dataset. Everything works fine in the IDE, however, I get an error in the generated designer code on the table adapter constructor.

The error is: (PE26) Class type expected.

Here is the generated code:

```
{ Presidents.PresidentsTableAdapters.USPRESIDENTSTableAdapter }

constructor Presidents.PresidentsTableAdapters.USPRESIDENTSTableAdapter;
begin
    self.ClearBeforeFill := true;
end;
```

Comment: @JimMcKeeth: I've cleaned up here.

Answer (score 0):

does it help to leave out the "self."?  i would expect "self." is unnecessary.  i use it only rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the full file? The error says that "Presidents.PresidentsTableAdapters.USPRESIDENTSTableAdapter" is not a known class type.